# Should dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier clear detailTextLabel before returning a cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell=[self._tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"event"];;
Event* event =[self eventForIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell==nil)
    cell=[[EventCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"event"];



UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 44.0f, cell.frame.size.height)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"van_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"location.png"]forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(carButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;


[[cell textLabel] setText:event.customer.name];

 if(event.startTime!=nil)
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:event.startTime];


 cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

 if(event.drivingTime!=0 && event.drivingDistance !=0)
            button.selected=YES;

[ cell.contentView addSubview:button];
return cell;
```

}

When a cell is reused I am getting a cell with the previous detailTextLabel. Meaning if I don't change the detailTextLabel string it is presented with it's previous text. Is this part of the functionality of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is functionality of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` not a bug. This function takes existing hidden cell with specific identifier. Thanks to that you create only few (usualy up to 10) `UITableViewCell` instances (that in some cases can be memory consuming).

Apple documentation:

> reuseIdentifier
>
> The reuse identifier is associated with a UITableViewCell object that the table-view’s delegate creates **with the intent to reuse it as
>   the basis (for performance reasons) for multiple rows of a table
>   view**. It is assigned to the cell object in
>   initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier: and cannot be changed thereafter. A
>   UITableView object maintains a queue (or list) of the currently
>   reusable cells, each with its own reuse identifier, and makes them
>   available to the delegate in the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
>   method.

Comment: Thanks, I read this part of the documentation, but it still seemed a bit ambiguous, therefore I decided to double check :)

Comment: It's usefull when you have over 100 cells. UITableViewCell is very resource consuming object, so it will be created only 10 times and later some data in cell will be changed when user scroll down. It's very popular topic on stack. Just google it :-)